# Do I need a sub-panel near my hot tub?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, hot-tub

I am getting a hot tub soon and need to pre wire it myself. This is my first house so I’m still learning all the electrical stuff.

When I was in the process of building, I requested the builder to put in a 240V connection in the backyard. It’s on its own breaker in the main panel in the garage (picture below). My question is, do I need to buy a sub panel box outside?

I already have a small box out there with the wires needed (pic below). If I do need a sub panel, what do I go with? The main breaker is 60 amps but the hot tub requires 50. I know I can either wire straight from the box provided if my main breaker is GFCI or sub panel with a GFCI switch. If I have to go with the latter what do I need? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Normally wiring like this could go into a GFCI disconnect and directly into a prewired hot tub. If you purchased individual parts, then you would go to a sub panel adding separate GFCI breakers for the heater and motor, etc..

Unfortunately the wiring provided is only good for 240 Volt,30 Amps. Two 30 Amp breakers do not equal a 60 Amp service.  It will not handle a hot tub the needs 50 Amps. You might be able to get a hot tub that only requires a 30 Amp circuit. If you do get a hot tub that requires a 50 Amp service, then you'll have to get larger wire run from your main panel to the hot tub and get a 50 Amp breaker.

Comment: I'm with you JACK! That circuit is way undersized for a hot tub unless it's a dinky-ass one person hot tub. That said, I believe at least a local disconnect is required, using a GFCI local disconnect solves both problems. 

And like JACK said, 2 30 amp breakers don't make 60 amps at 240v. They are good for 30 amps for 2 120v circuits, but not one 240v circuit.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I think I covered the local disconnect by saying "wiring like this could go into a GFCI disconnect and directly into a prewired hot tub.... and yes, it's required.